# Delegating a method to a class method with the same name in the ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates

So what I am trying to do is delegate the `format_text` method to the class level method so I wouldn't have two methods with the same name.  Is there a good pattern or way of doing this?  The reason for this is so that I can call `format_text` in both views and presenters.  I realize that it's probably not good practice to use the ApplicationHelper outside of views.

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # would like to do something like this:
  # delegate :format_text, to: self.format_text

  # all this method does is call self.format_text
  def format_text(text)
    # calls the class level method
    format_text(text)
  end

  # need the self. in front to use outside of view
  def self.format_text(text)
    # do something to the text and return a string
  end
end
```

A view uses the helper as such:

some_view.html.haml

```
%label= format_text('something needs formatting')
```

But in some cases the formatting needs to be down at the presenter level.  In this case to use the method `format_text` it has to be called like `ApplicationHelper.format_text`.

some_presenter.rb

```
def header_of_some_data
  "#{@name} blah #{ApplicationHelper.format_text('some text')}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [module_function](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#module_function-method) for it:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def format_text(text)
    # do something to the text and return a string
  end
  module_function :format_text
end

ApplicationHelper.format_text("text")
```